# I want to copy a specific row and two specific columns from my Azure Table Storage to my SQL Database Table using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage, chatbot, azure-data-factory

I have a chatbot that asks 3 questions then record the answers.

my Storage table looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWaGM.jpg

I also have a Azure SQL Database Table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Answers (
    Timestamp DateTimeOfsett,
    Data varchar(255),
);
```

I have set up a Azure Storage Factory following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-copy-activity-tutorial-using-azure-portal

I've been able to filter out the columns I don't want using the Schema function in Azure Data Factory in my inputDataSet however I also want to filter out all of the rows excep the one with RowKey "userData" however I can't for the life of me figure it out as I do not have any prior experience with Azure, SQL or javascript and have only gotten this far using google and microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would like to suggest you use azure data factory v2 as it is GA now and it has a more advanced UI. Though I think this is also achievable in v1.
2. You could reference this doc for [azure table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage).
3. You could use [ADF V2 UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal) to build and debug your pipeline.
4. For "filter out all of the rows excep the one with RowKey", You could specify [azureTableSourceQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage#copy-activity-properties)

Comment: Hello Liu, I believe I have tried to specify azureTableSourceQuery in ADF however it seems I have misunderstood something.

This is a image of what I've specified, https://imgur.com/W9KlJ73. 

I am getting an error that I can't figure out how to solve so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: This is my error:


`Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A storage operation failed with the following error &apos;The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.&apos;.,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,StorageExtendedMessage=Syntax error at position 13 in &apos;SELECT RowKey&#44; Timestamp&#44; Data
FROM botdata
WHERE RowKey &#61; &apos;userData&apos;;&apos;.`

Comment: In your inputtabledataset. make sure your table botdata is selected. in the query field, input RowKey eq 'userData'

Comment: Azure table doesn't use sql query. Please reference  #4 in my answer.